# How can I recursively traverse a React elements children and call a method on each?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First off I know this is not typically the "React way" to do thing. However this is for a very special case where I need to serialize a tree of elements in a sort of wysiwyg editor.

In summary I have a reference to a top level React Element, lets call it topElement. topElement has children and those children have children, etc.

I need to traverse through the whole child tree and call a function on any and all children that have the function "serialize". Here is what I got so far.

```
function serializeChildren(children){
    React.Children.map(children,(child)=>{

        //this is always undefined
        if(child.serialize !== undefined){
            let result = child.serialize()
            doSomethingWith(result)
        }

        if(child.props.children){
            serializeChildren(child.props.children)
        }
    })
}


function serializeChildren(topElement)
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#findallinrenderedtree) can bring you something? You could give the toplevel and the test for the serialization method?

Comment: What problem are you having?